# bookshelf/knex InnerJoin between multiple tables

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to do a join between three tables.

Let's call these tables, table a, b, and c.

Table a has a primary key that is the target of a foreign key from b.
Similarly, Table a's primary key is the target of a foreign key from c.

The end query I want to do is something like

`SELECT * FROM a WHERE b.foreign_key = a.primary_key OR c.foreign_key = a.primary_key`

My queryBuilder looks like this right now (starting from table a):

`qb.innerJoin('b', 'b.foreign_key', 'a.primary_key')
qb.innerJoin('c', 'c.foreign_key', 'a.primary_key')`

I think this is wrong because when we do the join for table c, it's acting off of the previous join between a and b.

Is there a way I can do this three-way join where the joins are kind of added to each other/concatted together instead?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I just needed to use a left join instead. Using a left join would preserve my original table (table a), and prevents it from being culled down like what was happening when I joined a with b.